# "status": 403, "error": "Forbidden", "message": "Forbidden", "path": "/post/create"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I see this response when I try to add new post after authorization by admin. 
I have Basic authorization which based on spring boot security:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    //...declared fields
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                .withUser("user")
                .password("userpass")
                .roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("admin")
                .password("adminpass")
                .roles("ADMIN", "USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/logout").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and().logout().permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

I get this message when try to add new post after authorization:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-07-04T12:19:25.638+0000",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "path": "/post/create"
}
```

in my controller:

```
@RestController
public class PostController {
    @Autowired
    private PostDAO postDAO;

    @GetMapping("/posts")
    public Page<Post> getAllPosts(Pageable pageable) {
        return postDAO.findAll(pageable);
    }

    @PostMapping("/post/create")
    public Post createPost(@Valid @RequestBody Post post) {
        return postDAO.save(post);
    }
    //other end-points........
}
```

However, read operations from my controller work well but to CRUD operation I haven't access.

There are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-core')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
    testCompile('junit:junit')
}
```

Any idea?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add the pattern /post in antMatchers

Comment: I did it-no result

Comment: You need to set jsession id in header and check csrf configuration

Comment: Do you have an example?Thnks

Comment: http .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll(); Try disable csrf.

Comment: Yuuhuuuuu! It works!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is due to `CSRF` enabled. `CSRF` protection is enabled by default in the Java configuration. We can still disable `CSRF` using the configuration given below.

```
http .csrf().disable() .authorizeRequests() .anyRequest().permitAll();
```

Starting from Spring **Security 4.x** – the `CSRF` protection is enabled by default in the XML configuration as well; we can of course still disable it if we need to:

```
<http>
    ...
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>
```

> Note : CSRF is an attack which forces an end user to execute unwanted
>   actions in a web application in which is currently authenticated.

Comment: Since Spring Security 5.7, the syntax in the Java configuration part of the answer is deprecated. But you can disable CSRF protection via http.csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable());

Answer (score 1):

here's why:
csrf is automatically enabled in spring security,and I recommended you do not disable csrf.
normally your html form tag should include a hidden field which generates csrf token, however, thymeleaf automaticlly do that for you, you should check your html  tag to see whether or not a "th:" was included, if not, include a "th:" before "action" in form tag, do this, thymeleaf generates csrf token invisibablly.